# Word for a meeting meant to persuade the other person

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, someone's intention for meeting a senator could be to convince them to enact some policy.

This would be in contrast to an interview where the caller of meeting was looking for information rather than an opportunity to persuade the other(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a "pitch meeting" or just a [pitch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch) ?

> 11. Informal 
>       a.  A line of talk designed to persuade: "[his] pious pitch for ... austerity" (Boston Globe).

The word is widely used for meetings aimed to "sell" a business or creative idea.

Example: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/jayson-demers/8-questions-that-entrepre_b_4747729.html

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping for something a little more subtle, but I suppose pitch will work. Thanks!